# How to set default date in DateField?

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-plugins, tapestry

In my ActivitiesFilterControl component, I have two `DateField`s, which (int the .tml file) are inside the `fieldset` section:

```
<fieldset class="float_right">

  <t:label for="dateFrom">${message:search.form.label.dateFrom}</t:label>
  <t:datefield t:id="dateFrom" t:mixins="jquery/CustomDatepicker" t:value="dateFrom"
               t:params="calendarParams.params" format="prop:calendarParams.dateFormat" messages="messages" class="datepicker"/>

  <t:label for="dateTo">${message:search.form.label.dateTo}</t:label>
  <t:datefield t:id="dateTo" t:mixins="jquery/CustomDatepicker" t:value="dateTo"
               t:params="calendarParams.params" format="prop:calendarParams.dateFormat" messages="messages" class="datepicker"/>

</fieldset>
```

CustomDatepicker is this one:
http://tapestry5-jquery.com/mixins/docscustomdatepicker

How can I set default values to the `CustomDatepicker`s/`DateField`s? Here is the sample code from the component:

```
public class ActivitiesFilterControl extends FilterControl {

  @Persist
  @Property
  private Date dateFrom;

  @Persist
  @Property
  private Date dateTo;

  @InjectComponent("dateFrom")
  private DateField dateFromField;

  @InjectComponent("dateTo")
  private DateField dateToField;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize your component's fields for the render phase, e.g. via a setup render annotated method:

```
@SetupRender
final void init() {
    dateFrom = new Date(); // or sthg else
    dateTo = new Date(); // or sthg else
}
```

(no need to inject the embedded components in your java class - attributes "dateFromField" and "dateToField" of your code)

Same thing for the `calendarParams` property you use for the `params` parameter of the CustomDatepicker mixin: you can initialize it at the same place.

This tells Tapestry the initial values to use to produce the HTML page sent back to your browser for display.

Note : Concerning form field values "dateFrom" & "dateTo", these values set in your `@SetupRender` method may be overriden by the ones memorised by the validation tracker, in case of a re-display of the page after validation errors have been detected.

Comment: Indeed, you are right - it was enough to set there values in setupRender method of my `Activities` page. Hard to admin, but it was not working, because I have had a bug there. Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/gd9xzP0a 
Reply to note: I think that this is the correct behavior. The values are set only for the first time user visits the page - they are saved for later use by @Persisten annotation (they can be set by user, my job is to ensure that the range is one month long at it maximum).

Comment: What bug did you encountered?
About your need of saving fields' values: the `@Persist` annotation defines the persistence strategy to use for an attribute **at session level**. If you need to keep these values up to 1 month, then you should rather think in terms of cookies persistence or database persistence.
Concerning cookies persistence, you can use the `org.apache.tapestry5.services.Cookies` service to ask the web client for saving your fields' values into cookies.

Comment: This bug was my _typo_. What about values: I do not keep them during one month, instead they keep dates, which range can be maximum one month. Sorry for not explaining this correctly;)

Comment: No problem. In that case, you can ensure the range is correct using Tapestry validation mechanisms (http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html).
But I still don't get it: you were speaking about a remaining bug, which one is it?